# Ozeki + Ubuntu 14.04 + MySQL

Tags: sms, ubuntu-14.04, sms-gateway, ozeki

I'm installing ozeki NG sms gateway in Ubuntu but I need to connect my ozeki in phpmyadmin, do I need a ODBC connector for ubuntu? I can't find any solution on the internet. Please help.

Thank you in advance.